# Invoke-Command Elevation Issue

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to run Invoke-Command with an answer file to the user credentials but I can't seem to get it to finish running.  I'm using a local administrator account so nothing on the domain.  Here is what I have and the error:

```
$Username = "$Env:Computername\admin"
$Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "12345" -AsPlainText -Force
$User = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $Pass)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Env:Computername -Credential $User -ScriptBlock { 
    $Path = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System'
    $Name = 'DontDisplayLastUserName'
    Set-ItemProperty -path $Path -name $Name -value 0
}
```

And the error:

```
[computer] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occured while using Kerberos authentication: There are curren
tly no logon servers available to service the logon request.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Working Solution:

```
$Username = "$Env:Computername\admin"
$Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "12345" -AsPlainText -Force
$User = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $Pass)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -Credential $User -ScriptBlock { 
    $Path = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System'
    $Name = 'DontDisplayLastUserName'
    Set-ItemProperty -path $Path -name $Name -value 0
}
```

Comment: I tried to use the following:

`winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="RemoteComputerName"}`

I keep getting the following error:

`winrm.cmd : Error: Invalid use of command line. Type "winrm -?" for help.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem, hit me kind of randomly.  The following line needed to be changed.

Before:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Env:Computername
```

After:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost
```

Without localhost it was looking at it like a remote computer and not allowing it access.